# Error when trying to modify a wiki

Tags: support, tags

I was trying to modify a wiki term and every time I click the edit button i get this error.

> Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days.

I have only tried to edit 1 wiki ever.. and it was accepted! What gives?

Answer (score 1):

The edits to which the error message is referring are not the suggested edits for the tag wiki pages, but any suggested edit. It means that most of your recent suggested edits have been rejected, and you cannot suggest further edits for the next seven days.

Suggested edits are generally rejected for four reasons:

- They are too minor, such as in the case you change *i* (first person singular) in *I* once, when the user keeps writing *i* instead of *I*.
- They are wrong, such in the case you remove "I am using Drupal 7," and add [7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7).
- They add to the post something that should be a comment, such as "This answer doesn't really answer what being asked."
- They are defacing the post in some way, such as replacing the text used in the post with "This is a bad answer."

Comment: As for reason 2, Isn't that the purpose of having the 7 tag? Also, my edits are mostly formatting and grammar corrections. Isn't that something that can be considered subjective? "Your edit is better than my edit" type of situation?

Comment: As any version tag, [tag:7] should be used when a question is specific for Drupal 7, not when the same answer applies for Drupal 5, Drupal 6, and Drupal 7. In any case, there isn't any reason to remove "I am using Drupal 7." from the post. Your suggested edits can be about formatting, and grammar corrections, but if they are too minor, they can still be rejected. Is there anything in the post that could be changed? If there is, then edit that part too, such as in the case of the OP writing _i_ for the first person singular.

Comment: @DigitalFire The issue with the 7 tag is/was a minefield, see the links in the answer to http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/703/what-is-the-rationale-behind-this-instruction-in-the-7-tag-wiki for some backgroun

Comment: I guess I will take my 7 day 'edit' suspension and consider it a learning pain.

Comment: By the way, when's the Dark Digital Era going live? I'm interested to know what the "darkside of technology" is ;)

Comment: Heh, I've been slacking on that project. Mostly built out functionality wise but haven't gotten around to creating content. It's going to focus on showing great technologies but how they all have a darker applications. Also, kinda of like my code lab.